# Null object reference even after the object has been initialized

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, okhttp

I am attempting to try my best at using fragments for this particular project I am trying to create. I am making all network calls inside a fragment class that I have created. When I call the methods that make the connection and I log the results to the console I am getting all the information from the class, but when I try to access the instance outside of the network call I get a null pointer exception.
I have been looking at the docs and at other examples, but most of them do things differently from what I need and the docs make no reference to working with ***okhttp*** inside fragments.

The code that I am using is this :

```
public void testAsyncCreate() {

        OkHttpClient client  = new OkHttpClient();


        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(CREATE_MEDIA_TYPE, "data={\"process\":\"123\", \"phone\":\"111111111\"}");


        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(ALLWAYS_API)
                .post(body)
                .build();

        Call call = client.newCall(request);

        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                // any additional runnable items go in here
                try {


                    String jsonData = response.body().string(); // the exception is caught at this point
                    Log.d("<Mensajes>",jsonData);
                    //extractCreate = parseExtractCreateDetails(jsonData);
                    if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                        extractCreate = parseExtractCreateDetails(jsonData);
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Log.d("<=====>", "check");
                                Log.d(TAG, "Is this even working?");
                                Log.d("The class has been ok",extractCreate.getCreateR().getAccount_id().toString());
                                Log.d("Another check", extractCreate.getStopsR()[1].getAddress());



                            }
                        });
                    }

                    //getStops(jsonData);

                }catch(IOException e) {

                }catch (JSONException e){

                }


            }
        });
    } // end of asyncCreate
```

Then inside the onCreateView() method:

```
ExtractCreate extractCreate = new ExtractCreate();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragments_stops_list, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
              testAsyncCreate();
        }
        Log.d("<extractCreateCheck>", String.valueOf(extractCreate.getCreateR().getAccount_id()));

        return view:
    }
```

I can´t figure why this is not working when using fragments, the reason I say that is because if I was to put this inside a regular activity and run it I would be able to use the results of extractCreate anywhere else I wanted, but not in here. Are there any steps that I am missing regarding using okhttp calls inside fragments? the docs are not really making any sense to me at the moment.
The stacktrace is as follows:

```
11-23 09:28:55.569 3288-3288/com.example.testC.demotrackertree E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                   
        Process: com.example.testC.demotrackertree, PID: 11142
        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String at com.example.testC.demotrackertree.models.createmodels.CreateResponse.getAccount_id()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.testC.demotrackertree.ui.fragments.StopCreateFragment.onCreateView(StopCreateFragment.java:95)
        at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2353)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:995)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1171)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:816)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1578)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:483)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

As one of the guys suggested, I did what I wanted to do inside of the response,

```
if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                        extractCreate = parseExtractCreateDetails(jsonData);
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
//                                Log.d("<=====>", "check");
//                                Log.d(TAG, "Is this even working?");
//                                Log.d("The class has been ok",extractCreate.getCreateR().getAccount_id().toString());
//                                Log.d("Another check", extractCreate.getStopsR()[1].getAddress());
                                Parcelable[] parcelable = extractCreate.getStopsR();

                                commodities = Arrays.copyOf(parcelable, parcelable.length, Stops[].class);
                                //Log.d("Commodities size check", String.valueOf(commodities.length));


                                StopsAdapter adapter = new StopsAdapter(extractCreate.getStopsR());
                                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()); // sketchy on this part
                                mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                                mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                                Log.d(TAG, "This is being called from the onCreate method");
                                //();



                            }
                        });
                    }

                    //getStops(jsonData);

                }catch(IOException e) {

                }catch (JSONException e){

                }


            }
```

Now the contents of the view update accordingly as I specified in my adapter(meaning that the adapter is functioning as I intended) but being that the adaptor is not added until the callback finishes the stack trace prints out

```
11-23 12:05:40.628 7270-7270/com.example.testC.demotrackertree E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

And not only that, but the saveInstanceState is not preserved when I rotate the screen.

Comment: Could you specify exactly where you get a null pointer?

Comment: Hint: one thing: you **never** go for **empty** catch blocks. Those indicate **errors** and ignoring errors rarely helps. Plus: you want to provide the complete exception stack trace.

Comment: @Sam absolutely, right at when I log the information inside the onCreateview method

Comment: @GhostCat forgot to add the stack trace, already there. Thanks for the hints btw

Comment: @sigillum_conf, what if you put inside onActivityCreated method?

Comment: @sigillum_conf That is better, but: please use the *preview* functionality and properly indent/format your code / stack traces. You want us to spend our time to help you, so you want to make that as easy as possible for us.

Comment: @Adley thanks for the tip! Unfortunately, this gave me the same result

Comment: @GhostCat you are absolutely right. Just changed it to make it easier to read. I apologize for the previous results. And thank you for the tip on formatting.

Comment: @sigillum_conf Much better ;-) ... and I think the answer from rhari already goes in the correct direction!

Comment: @sigillum_conf Have you extend AsyncTask class? I'm feeling your code structure strange for an asyncTask. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: @Adley I am going from the docs inside the okhttp library

Comment: @sigillum_conf Oh, sry. I didn't saw. If you make it bold or make clear that you using httpOk will help.

Comment: @Adley oh it was on me, already changed it, it is particularly hard to see among all the other text. Done btw!

Answer (score 3):

When you execute your AsyncTask, the operation runs on a background thread at the same time as the UI thread. The Log statement is right after the execute statement, so when the Log statement is executed, the AsyncTask has not loaded the information in the variable yet.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification rhari, I am still having a hard time grasping my head around getting the contents where I want them. How would I perform the required assignment then? As I mention previously, this works normally when not doing it inside a fragment. That is confusing me quite a bit.

Comment: If you want to access the returned variable in the onCreateView method, it will not be possible unless you use execute() instead of enqueue(). You should to whatever you want to the result in the onResponse callback. You can also use a BroadcastReceiver to send the result back to the main thread and execute custom code there.

Comment: that actually works and the rest of the code functions properly. In this case what I am trying to do is parse the contents of the request into an adapter and then a recycler view. It runs, but when I turn the screen the state is not saved and since the adapter is added and executed inside the async call it logs that no adapter is attached.

Comment: updated the question to show the next issue, at this time I really don´t know what to do

Comment: You should initialize and set the adapter with an empty arraylist before making the network call, then once you have the results you can tell the adapter to update the listview. Have a look at https://www.raywenderlich.com/126528/android-recyclerview-tutorial, the sample code does this. Also can you post your onSaveInstanceState implementation ?